# How to light the pilot for an old Gas Heater

Tags: hvac, gas, heater, baseboard

We have moved in to a new home (new for us!) and we noticed that there was no heat coming from the base board. I tried to read the instructions on the Gas Heater in the basement and it talks about the need to light the pilot. I've posted pictures of the instructions and the Heater below. I looked up this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfJ1DqcCUX8) to figure out how to light it. The instructions in the video are very similar to that of the instructions posted on the Heater.

But I'm not sure where the pilot is on the system, the knob to turn it off (I can turn it off the switch at the circuit break however). Can you guys help me locate it on the image below and any instructions that can help us? Thanks.

[image: meter]
[image: heater1]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That lower panel on the front of the boiler unit slides upwards and lifts away to expose the pilot light assembly. I recommend using one of the those long, bendable neck butane candle lighters. I had one of these units in my last place. I googled: peerless boiler lighting instructions  - This was on the results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwiTEou08FY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the gas company.

If they aren't also the power company and there isn't a power crisis like a wind storm, then they'll often send someone out to light it for you for free.

The gas company's perspective is *they would **much** rather make a service call than have you attempt to light it and fail* (e.g. Due to an obsolete or defective valve) and blow your house up.  That also lets them put eyes on your setup, do a safety check, and give you advice if you need it.  If they have conservation incentive programs that your unit qualifies for, they can have that conversation with you too.